# Power BI SUMIFS

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm quite new on using DAX. What I want is to sum a segment from another table. Here's what I have.

```
Billed Revenue = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(FBB_Sales_Info[FBB MRR (vat-ex)]),
        FILTER(
            FBB_Sales_Info,
            EARLIER('Team Performance'[Team]) = [Team]
        ))
```

But when I filter from FBB Sales Info table my chart did not filter the Performance column.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to make these calculations as measures, not calculated columns. Only measures can respond to selections, calculated columns are computed only once when you create them or reload data.

Comment: Yes @RADO is true! If your calculations need to dynamically respond to changes in filters, slicers, or selections, always use measures. If you must use calculated columns for some reason... You should try to use  RELATEDTABLE() function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/relatedtable-function-dax. 

For a better answer, you should upload more info about your data model and relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this question as the calculated measure solves my problem. Thank you all :)